# How to free memory of a char pointer inside a struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm able to assign values with `strdup` and print the values with this: `(*test + index)->email` but I have no idea how to free the memory allocated to the variable email. I thought about freeing `test+index` but I guess this would cause a memory leak, right? Taking into account that the struct has allocated memory and each of the pointer inside it have memory allocated with `strdup`.

**Edit:**

The code is roughly like this:

```
struct random {
    char *email;
} Random;

void function(Random **struct) {
    char *temp = calloc(100, sizeof(char));
    *struct = calloc(5, sizeof(Random));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        scanf("%s", temp);
        (*struct + i)->email = strdup(temp); //This works
    }
    free((*struct + 3)->email); //Gives segmentation fault
}

int main() {
    Random *struct;

    function(&struct)
}
```

Comment: Did you omit any code here? Because `scanf` into uninitialized `temp` is going to be undefined behavior. `temp` needs to be `malloc`ed, or made into an array, not just a `char*`. Also, you use `*struct + i` here, which makes no sense, given there is no `i` variable, nor a `randomSize` variable.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, I tried to simplify the example as much as possible. I forgot the malloc part. temp is initialized with calloc.

Comment: why are you adding `i` ? you are going to have to put in enough code to repro the issue

Comment: You're going to need to provide an *actual* [MCVE] (make sure it compiles, runs, and has the same error as your full code), we can't just guess at what other mistakes you're making when you chop up the code this badly.

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.4.1 Keywords](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.1p1), your use of `struct` as a variable name is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, wouldn't it this?

```c
free(*(test+index)->email);
free(text+index);
```

Comment: I get a segumentation fault when I try that. Maybe the edit might clarify things? I'm not sure.

Comment: It would be `free((*(test + index))->email)`, I think.  Or, better, `free(test[index]->email); and `free(text[index]);`.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code does not compile:

- you cannot use `struct` as the name of a variable. `struct` is a keyword.
- `Random` is a global variable, not a type.

It is idiomatic and much simpler in C to return the result instead of passing its address as an argument.

Following these remarks, and adding basic checks, the code should be simplified as:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Random {
    char *email;
} Random;

Random *function(void) {
    char *temp = calloc(100, sizeof(char));
    if (temp == NULL)
        return NULL;
    Random *s = calloc(5, sizeof(Random));
    if (s != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (scanf("%99s", temp) != 1)
                *temp = '\0';
            (s + i)->email = strdup(temp); //This works
        }
        free((s + 3)->email); //Gives segmentation fault
    }
    free(temp);
    return s;
}

int main() {
    Random *s = function();
    // ...
}
```

This code, semantically equivalent to your posted fragment, does not have undefined behavior where you indicate, your actual code must be doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

please read/understand: [precedence of C operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators_precedence.htm)

Then note that the de-reference operator `*` has a lower precedence than the `+` operator,

Therefore, The posted code needs to be modified to use something like:

```
(*mystruct)+i = ...
```

etc.  Otherwise, the `+` will be executed before the `*`

Comment: unary `*` evaluates **before** binary `+`, which is usually referred to as having *higher* precedence, not lower. `*s + i` is equivalent to `(*s) + i`, the parentheses do not change anything.